# Missing parenthesis for case statement

Tags: sql

While running the below SQL I'm getting an error:

> Missing parenthesis

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    RPH.transport_mode, PCP.air_export_ind, PCP.air_import_ind  
FROM
    RATE_PROFILE_HEADER RPH, PARTNER_CHARGE_PROFILE PCP
WHERE
    PCP.charge_code = RPH.Charge_code 
    AND PCP.charge_calculation_method = 'R'                     
    AND RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.CHARGE_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID 
    AND CASE '&psTransport_mode' 
           WHEN 'A' 
              THEN (DECODE(RPH.transport_mode, 'ALL', 'A', RPH.transport_mode) = 'A') AND (PCP.air_export_ind = 'Y' or PCP.air_import_ind = 'Y') 
           WHEN 'M' 
              THEN (DECODE(RPH.transport_mode, 'ALL', 'M', RPH.transport_mode) = 'M') AND (PCP.air_export_ind = 'Y' or PCP.air_import_ind = 'Y') 
           ELSE NULL
        END
```

I want to pass multiple conditions in `THEN` for `WHERE` clause.

Should I have to use an `IF` statement?

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You can't set values in a THEN,  you can only specify the value that is to be returned by the CASE statement. It appears that you are getting SQL confused with a programming language. What are you trying to do here? Perhaps we can guide you to the appropriate solution.

Comment: i want to use it under Where clause. If i pass the parameter A then it should pass this: ( Decode(RPH.transport_mode,'ALL','A',RPH.transport_mode) = 'A') AND (PCP.air_export_ind = 'Y' or PCP.air_import_ind = 'Y')   under WHERE clause to filter the result

Comment: 1) That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: 2) In WHERE and ON clauses it's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your advise jarlh..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about not using a CASE statement at all.  It seems like you just need a nested conditional:

```
Select 
    distinct 
    RPH.transport_mode,
    PCP.air_export_ind,
    PCP.air_import_ind  
from 
    RATE_PROFILE_HEADER RPH, 
    PARTNER_CHARGE_PROFILE PCP
where 
    PCP.charge_code = RPH.Charge_code 
AND PCP.charge_calculation_method = 'R'                     
AND RPH.RP_RECORD_ID = PCP.CHARGE_RATEPROF_RECORD_ID 
AND 
    (
        '&psTransport_mode' = 'A' AND ( Decode(RPH.transport_mode,'ALL','A',RPH.transport_mode) = 'A') AND (PCP.air_export_ind = 'Y' or PCP.air_import_ind = 'Y') 
    OR
        '&psTransport_mode' = 'M' AND ( Decode(RPH.transport_mode,'ALL','M',RPH.transport_mode) = 'M') AND (PCP.air_export_ind = 'Y' or PCP.air_import_ind = 'Y') 
    )
```